# java syntax help for noobie

Tags: java, python, jpype

Can anybody explain what does JdClient is in this code:

```
public JdClient client = new DefaultJdClient("some args")
```

and how to implement this in python with Jpype

Comment: JdClient is not a standard Java API class. It is hard to say what does this class do. It may do anything.

Comment: this classes compiled in jar file and i can't look how they works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It creates a `public` variable named `client` of type `JdClient` by calling the `DefaultJdClient` constructor with some arguments.

To use it in Python would be something along these lines, although can't be certain as I just did a cursory glances over the documentation, and I have no idea where JdClient comes from so there might be a need to import that Java library and reference it as needed, like one would do `java.lang.System.out.println('hello world')`

```
from jpype import *
startJVM("d:/tools/j2sdk/jre/bin/client/jvm.dll", "-ea")
client = DefaultJdClient("hello world")
shutdownJVM()
```